# What is the magnetic analog of resistivity?

Tags: electromagnetism

Would the magnetic analog of resistivity be the inverse of permeability?  I ask this because resistivity is defined by E/J, and so taking the magnetic analogs as H/B, I see that this is simply the inverse of permeability.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe that "magnetic resistivity" is referred to as [reluctance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_reluctance) (inverse of [permeance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permeance)) and is given in units of \$A\cdot\text{turns}/Wb\$ (Amp-turns per [weber](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weber_%28unit%29)) in an equivalent magnetic circuit. Reluctance can be calculated as:

$$\mathcal{R} = \frac{F}{\phi}$$

where \$F=N \cdot i\$ is the magnetomotive force and \$\phi=B\cdot A\$ is the flux, thus giving:

$$\text{reluctance} = \mathcal{R} = \frac{l}{\mu\cdot A}$$

Reluctance is defined by the magnetic permeability of the material (as well as its physical dimensions) which is given as:

$${\mu = \mu_0\mu_r}$$

Where \$\mu_0\$ is the magnetic constant and \$\mu_r\$ is the relative permeability of the material. Magnetic permeability is a measure of how easily a magnetic field is formed within the material and is affected by temperature, humidity, and magnetic field strength (among other things).

Hopefully someone can provide a more complete answer, as this is just off the top of my head.

Comment: I believe that's the analog of resistance, not of resistivity (the bulk property).

Comment: Agreed Brian Drummond.  Reluctance and Resistance are analogs in their respective magnetic and electric circuits.  Resistance of a material is defined by its resistivity, so then what material property defines the Reluctance of a material?

Comment: I fixed up my answer a bit, and hopefully it answers the question a bit better.

Comment: What is \$i\$? Is it the electric current? If it is so, this does not make sense. Consider the case of a straight infinitely long wire with constant current \$i\$ through it. The magnetic field \$\vec B\$ is perpendicular and circular around the current \$\vec i\$. 
What is $A$? Is it, say, a perpendicular disk or any compact and simply connected surface  around \$\vec i\$? If so, the flux \$\phi\$ (perpendicularly) through \$A\$ is zero! Unless you subscribe to a different \$A\$, the relation \$F=\mathcal R \phi\$ does not hold.